# Dynamically change object dimensions in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using the library `dat.gui` within `three.js` to let the user interact with an object and modify the dimensions of its mesh. Most of the examples online are using `scale` when they want to change a mesh dimensions:

```
mesh.onChange(function(value){mesh.scale.x = value;});
```

The problem with this solution is that is not very user friendly and requires to also adjust the `object.position` when a value is changed.
Are there other possibilities apart from this one? In case can you post a plausible alternative with a working example? Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clue to solving your question is to understand where the origin of your object is :  at the object's geometric center or at some corner.  It also depends on the implementation of the scale operation.

Ignoring three.js for a minute, if done by hand a scale operation could be thought of as three distinct operations :

```
1 - translate the object center to the origin of your world coordinates
2 - multiply its vertex position matrix by your scale factor
3 - translate object back to original world location
```

So two assumptions need to get resolved :

```
- is the ~center~ of your object at its geographic center or 
  at one of its corners

- do you want to scale (stretch) your object by expanding outwards from 
  its origin in all dimensions or simply extend outwards by retaining
  its current origin and ballooning its shape outwards
```

What behavior you need expressed ?

.... object.position would be needed depending on your answer

Comment: Your answer makes sense and I have to say that your tips are quite useful. Thank you!! I still wonder if there is an alternative to `mesh.scale` to dynamically change an object dimension...